# nginx php file rewrite url

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

so with apache i have a folder:

www.domain.com/folder/folder1/index.php?word=blahblah

and i want users who access www.domain.com/folder/folder1/blahblah to be redirected to the above URL without the url changing.

Thus i have the following .htaccess in the folder/folder1/ which works perfectly:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?word=$1
```

So i want to achieve the same functionality with nginx and i used two converters:
http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/ results in:

```
if (!-f $request_filename){
    set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if (!-d $request_filename){
    set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "21"){
    rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?word=$1;
}
```

and http://winginx.com/htaccess results in:

```
 if (!-e $request_filename){ rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?word=$1; }
```

now, i tried with both but neither works. I tried inserting them either in

```
location / {
}
```

or in

```
location /folder/folder1 {
}
```

or in

```
location ~ \.php$ {
}
```

in all locations i get a 404 error

nginx error reports either "primary script unknown while reading response header from upstream" or "no such file or directory".

can someone enlighten me please ?

thanks in advance!

Comment: ``rewrite ^(.*(?![\.js|\.css])[^.]+)$ /index.php/$1 last;`` rewrites all ignoring only js and css files ... I was brought here with that problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, don't use `if`. If is evil -> http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil

You can accomplish this by using the following rewrite rule.

```
rewrite ^/folder/folder1/(.*)$ /folder/folder1/index.php?word=$1 last;
```

Place this rewrite rule just above you `location / {}` block

Comment: this kind of works. it has two problems:
a) it does not avoid the problem of calling /folder/folder1/existing_file.txt
b) the css is screwed up, no css at all